# how to solve white label error . yesterday when I started tomcat server through xampp then my restApi didn't responed anything

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-maven-plugin

- When I start Application (Console):

2023-03-03T21:15:12.443+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 16580 (D:\extras\SPRING\Coding Moments\Spring Boot\springRestApiCM\demo\target\classes started by HP in D:\extras\SPRING\Coding Moments\Spring Boot\springRestApiCM\demo)

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.449+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.996+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.018+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.486+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.498+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.499+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.604+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.604+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1096 ms

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.765+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.809+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.060+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.411+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@76a1146d

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.413+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.456+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mSQL dialect [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.724+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.734+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:15.082+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:15.091+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started DemoApplication in 3.033 seconds (process running for 3.727)

when I Refresh page then (Console):

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.443+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 16580 (D:\extras\SPRING\Coding Moments\Spring Boot\springRestApiCM\demo\target\classes started by HP in D:\extras\SPRING\Coding Moments\Spring Boot\springRestApiCM\demo)

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.449+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.996+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.018+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.486+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.498+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.499+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.604+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.604+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1096 ms

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.765+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.809+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.060+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.411+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@76a1146d

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.413+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.456+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mSQL dialect [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.724+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.734+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:15.082+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:15.091+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started DemoApplication in 3.033 seconds (process running for 3.727)

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.503+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.503+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.505+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms

And When i close Application then (Console):

2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.443+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 16580 (D:\extras\SPRING\Coding Moments\Spring Boot\springRestApiCM\demo\target\classes started by HP in D:\extras\SPRING\Coding Moments\Spring Boot\springRestApiCM\demo)

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.449+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:12.996+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.018+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 13 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.486+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.498+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.499+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.604+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.604+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1096 ms

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.765+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:13.809+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.060+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.411+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@76a1146d

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.413+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.456+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mSQL dialect [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.724+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:14.734+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:15.082+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''

[2m2023-03-03T21:15:15.091+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ main][0;39m [36mcom.springRestApi.DemoApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started DemoApplication in 3.033 seconds (process running for 3.727)

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.503+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.503+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.505+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.356+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36minMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application shutdown requested.

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.373+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.375+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.384+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.386+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.395+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

There are some exceptions:

2023-03-03T21:17:42.503+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.503+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:17:42.505+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.356+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36minMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application shutdown requested.

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.373+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.375+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.384+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.386+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...

[2m2023-03-03T21:21:05.395+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m16580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[n(15)-127.0.0.1][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

///////////////ScreenShots///////////////////////

```
Browser:          [enter image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltIJO.png)
```

console :             [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrJO3.png) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltIJO.png)

Comment: please edit your question with applied of these rules -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.